# How does changing path length to align phase of two pairs of down-converted photons automatically create a GHZ quantum state between pairs?

Tags: quantum-entanglement, photonics

The problem

At least one StackExchange physicist suggests "In an ideal laser, there is no entanglement whatsoever between successive emerging photons. This occurs because a laser state is supposed to be a coherent state (Glauber state) of the electromagnetic field". See here [Are photons in laser entangled?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/446749/are-photons-in-laser-entangled)

However, in the same thread, AnnaV responds: "I think you should hold your horses a bit, lasing is a quantum mechanical phenomenon and if a single wave function can be obtained for the system there may be entanglement".

And [this experiment](https://arxiv.org/abs/0705.1684) demonstrates a Greenberger-Horne-Zeilinger (GHZ) quantum state between pairs of entangled photons from temporally and spatially separated down-converted photon pairs:[image: Demonstration of Shor’s quantum factoring algorithm using photonic qubits] by aligning the phase through altering path length (and adding polarizing beam splitter, wave plates and other components).

My intuition is that entanglement is a fundamental property of nature, inherent everywhere, so pervasive that it would be surprising not to find it exiting a laser. It seems more likely than not that across the Gaussian distribution of the original laser emission there are trillions of coherent photons, generally polarized, millions of which are created at either a similar time (within femtoseconds) or integer multiples of wavelengths apart, sufficiently temporal to entangle and exit the laser entangled.

If my intuition is wrong, and the aligned phase from a laser produces coherence and polarization but is insufficient for entanglement, then how is it possible to entangle subsequent pairs of down-converted pairs into a GHZ state by changing path length and adding the other components?

Research I did before asking my question

I separated the issue of producing entangled photon pairs from detecting entanglement (see here for how to detect entanglement:
[How to tell whether photons are entangled?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/132048/how-to-tell-whether-photons-are-entangled?rq=1))
I also reviewed ["Entanglement Detection"](https://arxiv.org/abs/0811.2803) by Géza Tóth as it did touch on production of entangled particles and the creation of GHZ states, but it's very dense and doesn't specifically answer this question.

Through the experiment of Browne et al of 2007 and many other similar experiments since, it is not only possible but also a fundamental requirement that changing path length creates a GHZ state between multiple pairs of down-converted entangled photons.

Comment: https://physicsworld.com/a/laser-beams-are-entangled-in-space/  "physicists have also been able to entangle much larger entities such as laser beams, which contain many photons. This is possible because a laser beam can be created in a single electromagnetic mode, which can be described as a specific quantum state. " related to my comment you quote.